# Register service worker without access to local files

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-hosting, same-origin-policy, webflow

I'm attempting to build a PWA using Webflow, a web development tool. It is a web design platform, and it also manages hosting. It allows me to embed code into `<head>` or after the document, but it doesn't allow me to add any files to the server. I'm using a `data:` url to add a manifest file, which is working well. However, I'm finding it difficult to add a service worker.

I tried hosting the `service-worker.js` file on another server, and used `navigator.serviceWorker.register('url_of_sw.js')` but it gives me an origin error: `ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('script_url') does not match the current origin ('site_url').`

I tried a `data:` url by using `navigator.serviceWorker.register('data:encoded_data')` and it says that the protocol is not supported.

Is there any way to register a service worker without access to the local filestore? I know I can do it if I have control of a subdomain by setting `document.domain`. I want to assume I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a browser security restriction. Just imagine, someone XSS this site, then all of the request will be control. It is dangerous.

Only service worker has this limit. For WebWorker, you can try:

```js
const makeWorker = (workerFn) => {
  const fnStr = `(${workerFn.toString()})()`;
  const fnBolb = new Blob([fnStr]);
  const fnUrl = URL.createObjectURL(fnBolb);
  const worker = new Worker(fnUrl);
  return worker;
};
```